# Show multivariable quadratic function is continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

I want to show that $f(x)=x^TAx+c^Tx$ where $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $c$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function.
Using the definition we have:

$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \,\,\,\, \|x-x_c\| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_c)| < \varepsilon.
$$
where $\| \cdot\|$ is Euclidean norm.

So using triangle inequality we have

$$
|f(x)-f(x_c)|=|x^TAx+c^Tx-x_c^TAx_c-c^Tx_c| \leq |x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c|+|c^Tx-c^Tx_c|
$$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz we have

$$
|x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c|+|c^Tx-c^Tx_c| \leq |x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c|+ \|c\| \|x-x_c\|
$$
To have $|x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c|$ in terms of $\|x-x_c\|$ we need to do something which I do not know?

Maybe

$$
|x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c|=|x^TAx-x^TAx_c+x^TAx_c-x_c^TAx_c|
$$

Please complete this answer not starting new one.

Comment: You're almost there. Use the triangle inequality again and the Cauchy Schwarz inequality as you did for the linear term and then use that linear transformations are bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing

$\Vert x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c \Vert =\Vert x^TAx-x^TAx_c+x^TAx_c-x_c^TAx_c \Vert \tag 1$

is certainly on the right track, and indeed very close to the station, since

$\Vert x^TAx-x^TAx_c+x^TAx_c-x_c^TAx_c \Vert \le \Vert x^TAx-x^TAx_c \Vert + \Vert x^TAx_c-x_c^TAx_c \Vert$
$= \Vert x^TA(x - x_c) \Vert + \Vert (x^T - x_c^T)Ax_c \Vert \le \Vert x^T A \Vert \Vert x - x_c \Vert + \Vert x^T - x_c^T \Vert \Vert Ax_c \Vert; \tag 2$

now $x_c$ is fixed, hence so is $\Vert A x_c \Vert$; and also

$\Vert x^T A \Vert \le \Vert x^T \Vert \Vert A \Vert; \tag 3$

if now

$\Vert x - x_c \Vert < \delta, \tag 4$

then

$\vert \Vert x \Vert - \Vert x_c \Vert \vert \le \Vert x - x_c \Vert < \delta, \tag 5$

which implies that

$\Vert x \Vert < \Vert x_c \Vert + \delta; \tag 6$

furthermore, in the Euclidean norm

$\Vert x^T \Vert = \Vert x \Vert, \tag 7$

and thus (3) becomes

$\Vert x^T A \Vert \le \Vert x \Vert \Vert A \Vert < (\Vert x_c \Vert + \delta) \Vert A \Vert; \tag 8$

we may now assemble (1), (2) and (8) together and write

$\Vert x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c \Vert \le (\Vert x_c \Vert + \delta) \Vert A \Vert  \Vert x - x_c \Vert +  \Vert x - x_c \Vert \Vert Ax_c \Vert$
$= ((\Vert x_c \Vert + \delta) \Vert A \Vert  + \Vert Ax_c \Vert) \Vert x - x_c \Vert, \tag 9$

whenever $x$ is such that (4) binds.
Then to attain

$\Vert x^TAx-x_c^TAx_c \Vert < \epsilon, \tag{10}$

we need only ensure

$\Vert x - x_c \Vert < \min \{((\Vert x_c \Vert + \delta) \Vert A \Vert  + \Vert Ax_c \Vert)^{-1} \epsilon, \delta \}, \tag{11}$

and we have established the requisite continuity *via* what is essentially an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.